# Error when I want to remove folder names from the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I classify my files like this:

```
- root
    - javascript
    - stylesheets
    - views
        - users
            - login.php
            - logout.php
            - editprofile.php
            - dashboard.php
        - datas
        - etc ...
```

**The current links are:**

```
http://example.com/views/users/login.php
http://example.com/views/users/editprofile.php
```

**But I would like to remove the folder name "views" in the links so that the url looks like this:**

```
http://example.com/users/login.php
http://example.com/users/editprofile.php
```

I have to search on stackoverflow a solution, I tried this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ views/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

But I can not access the pages with any url (.../users/login.php or .../views/users/login.php)

```
Not Found
The requested URL /users/login.php was not found on this server.
```

With :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ views /(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

The link changes in the address bar but I have the same error

Do you have a solution ?
**I just wish that the user does not see this folder**

Thank you

Comment: C'est plutot l'inverse, tu veux que ta rewrite Rule ajouter views alors que tu ne l'as pas mis dans l'url. c'est plutot un truc du genre :

    RewriteRule ^ /(.*)$ /views /$1 [L]

Comment: Ah un Français c'est rare :) Non a la base l'url contient le views et moi je souhaiterais l'enlever (pour cacher un peu l'arborescence aux utilisateurs
Je viens de tester ta solution, le lien ne fonctionne pas sans le "/views/"

Comment: hello, french should speak english as the code of honor of stack overflow ;)
I promiss you this is the right solution.
You ask for "http://example.com/users/login.php" and the rewrite Rule add the views but this is transparent for you. You will see http://example.com/users/login.php but the real url is "http://example.com/views/users/login.php"

Answer (score 0):

here is the share solution with htaccess tester

http://htaccess.mwl.be/?share=be357d78-a41b-54e4-a578-10aceb8c6033

you can see the new url generated with the views inside.

regards.

Comment: When I put in my address bar: http://exemple.com/views/users/login.php
The url turns into : http://exemple.com/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/views/users/login.php
With your solution

Comment: I think i don't understand, do you want views in your url or not ?

Comment: I already have the "views" in my address bar, I would like to remove it! not the contrary

Did I express myself badly on my first article?

Comment: this is not the way htaccess can help you... i m sorry.
it can help you in the contrary way.

Comment: I want that when the user goes on : exemple.com/users/login.php It accesses the page that situates here: exemple.com/views/users/login.php 

And so he never sees the "views" folder, Thank you for your help, I hope to have been clearer :/

Comment: is this is what you say http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=77aaf2d4-daa0-5a27-b484-47c2b50dc92a

the one i post you before say this scenario:
when a man hit  exemple.com/users/login.php it will hit  exemple.com/views/users/login.php but you will see in the browser the url 
exemple.com/users/login.php

Comment: according to your last comment, the right solution is the first i give you.
you will not see views in the browser url, htaccess make it transparent, but will add the views for accesssing the file.

Comment: Thank you, thr url change but why I have a blank page with this message : **"Not Found

The requested URL /users/dashboard.php was not found on this server."***